# How can I uniquely identify a specific row in TSQL based on a comparison of a decimal value in a prior row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have got myself in a right pickle with this one and clearly cannot see the wood for the trees! I have a set of values currently returned like this:

[image: Grid showing data to use to calculate the required values]

Based on the value in ContractNumber and ContractSubNumber, for each row with a .1 value I need to retrieve the Fee of that row, deduct that from the Fee in the matching row without the .1, and assign the resulting value to the calculated profit column on the first row as shown in red for the first two result rows. Normally the .1 row would be excluded from the results by excluding PartId value 1 from the results, but I have included them here for clarity (hopefully).

My problem is that I cannot get a result with a single valid value - SQL Server either returns null or complains that the result can contain multiple rows in various circumstances. I have everything working perfectly apart from this one last step and I seem to have 'painted myself into a corner' with it.

I first got back multiple rows, so I tried to deal with that by removing the decimal portion and comparing with the prior value, but that returns nothing. Here is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT Lines.[Fee], Lines.[Commission], Lines.ContractNumber, Lines.ContractSubNumber, 
Lines.[PartId], 
CASE WHEN PartId = 2 THEN
    Lines.FEE - (SELECT Fee FROM Lines l2 WHERE l2.[ContractNumber] = ContractNumber AND l2.[PartId] = 1
    AND l2.[ContractSubNumber] % 1 > 0 AND l2.[ContractSubNumber] - l2.[ContractSubNumber] % 1 = ContractSubNumber)
ELSE 
    0
END AS Profit
FROM Lines
WHERE ContractNumber IN (16,18);
```

**Notes:**

1. The ContractNumber filter was used to limit the rows for a workable example. In the real world there could be hundreds or even thousands of rows to process and the main filter would be date based.
2. The ContractSubNumber can only be the whole value or the same value plus .1 - no other values to worry about
3. The .1 row will always have a lower or equal Fee than the matching row without the .1 so no negative value worries

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

**EDIT**

This has to operate with multiple database engines. Although they all support TSQL or a subset of it, not all support things like OVER, PARTITION etc.

All columns are Decimal, except PartId which is Int.

**Data as CSV:**

```
Fee,Commission,ContractNumber,ContractSubNumber,PartId,Profit
900,0,16,0,2,
800,0,16,0.1,1,0
900,0,16,1,2,
800,0,16,1.1,1,0
900,0,16,2,2,
800,0,16,2.1,1,0
900,0,16,3,2,
800,0,16,3.1,1,0
900,0,16,4,2,
800,0,16,4.1,1,0
900,0,16,5,2,
800,0,16,5.1,1,0
900,0,18,0,2,
100,0,18,0.1,1,0
```

Comment: What are the types of the columns?

Comment: FYI: I am pretty sure that In a subquery unqualified column names will attach to "closest" table with that column name.    So your `l2.[ContractNumber] = ContractNumber` is actually referring to the same column on both sides.  I think that it should be `l2.[ContractNumber] = Lines.ContractNumber` instead.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: If you are right then I really am an idiot! I will check.... Nope, makes no difference.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I did state decimal in the question? The exception is PartId which is Int.

Comment: Well if it's the other way around, then the `(Select Fee ..` part would be referring to the Fees column in the outer Lines table, so one or the other is wrong.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Surely that is handled by the following alias? I added an explicit table assignment and it made no difference.

Comment: Could you supply the data in either [tabluar text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) form or else using INSERTS?  [Images aren't as useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) because we cannot copy them into a database for testing.

Comment: _they all support TSQL_ There is no such thing as "plain TSQL". Seems you meant ANSI SQL - another term that does not really mean much since every database engine is free to implement the SQL language however they desire.

Comment: I will add tabular test data shortly. INSERTS are possible but would take a lot longer to generate...

Comment: I went ahead and did my data manually  ...  you can just copy from my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I believe this will do what you want.

First here's my definition of your table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE Lines(Fee DECIMAL(18,2), Commission INT, ContractNumber INT, ContractSubNumber DECIMAL(12,1), PartID INT)
go
INSERT INTO Lines VALUES
    (900,0,16,0,2),
    (800,0,16,0.1,2),
    (900,0,16,1,2),
    (800,0,16,1.1,2),
    (900,0,16,2,2),
    (800,0,16,2.1,2),
    (900,0,16,3,2),
    (800,0,16,3.1,2),
    (900,0,16,4,2),
    (800,0,16,4.1,2),
    (900,0,16,5,2),
    (800,0,16,5.1,2),
    (900,0,18,0,2),
    (100,0,18,0.1,2)
;
GO
```

Now here's the Query.  This is basically your query with a few corrections to the CASE WHEN conditions, the subquery column aliases, and most importantly, the subquery conditon that `l2.[PartId] = 1`  I am pretty sure that this should be 2 rather than 1, and with that change it works:

```
SELECT Lines.[Fee], Lines.[Commission], Lines.ContractNumber, Lines.ContractSubNumber, 
Lines.[PartId], 
CASE WHEN PartId = 2 AND (ContractSubNumber % 1) = 0 THEN
    Lines.FEE - (SELECT Fee FROM Lines l2 
                 WHERE ContractNumber = Lines.ContractNumber 
                   AND l2.[PartId] = 2 -- *** Was =1 ***
                   AND l2.[ContractSubNumber] % 1 > 0 
                   AND l2.[ContractSubNumber] - (l2.[ContractSubNumber] % 1) = Lines.ContractSubNumber)
ELSE 
    0
END AS Profit
FROM Lines
WHERE ContractNumber IN (16,18);
```

Comment: Thanks - actually it does need to be 1 rather than 2, with with that change it gets me exactly where I need to be. Thank you so much for going to that much trouble. I will accept your answer now!

Comment: @oldcoder Yep, I entered the data wrong.  That's why we like the question-askers to supply the data.

Comment: I am sorry, and in future I will make sure that I add data. My thinking was that the data was so simple that it was better to show the problem visually. I will do both next time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can calculate the total fee with window functions and arithmetic:

```
select l.*,
       (case when contractsubnumber % 1 <> 1
             then sum(fee) over (partition by contractnumber, floor(contractsubnumber))
        end) as totalfee
from lines l;
```

You can just subtract this amount from the profit.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the input. I am sorry, but I cannot use your solution as one of the databases in use (VistaDB) does not support it. It needs to be plain TSQL.  I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: @oldcoder Gordon's answer is only TSQL.  "Plain TSQL" isn't a thing, AFAIK.  Can you point us to VistaDB's limitations wrt SQL/TSQL?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to help which are very much appreciated: link as requested: https://doc.vistadb.com/Sql_Differences.html

Comment: @oldcoder . . . Your question is tagged SQL Server and this works in every supported version of SQL Server and many unsupported ones as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: You are of course correct and I apologise again if I was unclear. I did update the question following on from your answer. I was not able to add additional tags when I first asked the question, and I needed the answer to work with multiple database engines. The answer I accepted from RBarryYoung achieved that requirement and works with all the database engines I need. I am still grateful for your answer, and will try to learn the lessons both you and RBarry gave for any future questions.